# setting up linux routing table for mutliple wifi connections

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, routing

I would like to increase the speed when downloading large files on a public hotspot by using both a built-in wifi-adapter (wlan0) and a wifi-usb-stick (wlan1).

As bonding wifi-devices does not seem to be possible (or is it?) my plan is to configure a round-robin routing in style of http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html and achive better download-speeds by using a download-manager like aria2c that uses several connections (which in my setup would then be distributed across the wifi-connections).

The problem I am facing is how to setup the main routing table for this.

The situation is the following:

Two wifi-nics connected to the same ap like this:

wlan0, ip 10.22.11.131/24, gateway 10.22.11.1

wlan1, ip 10.22.11.162/24, gateway 10.22.11.1

I have setup two routing tables T0 and T1 like this:

```
sudo ip route add 10.22.11.0 dev wlan0 src 10.22.11.131 table T0
sudo ip route add 10.22.11.0 dev wlan0 src 10.22.11.163 table T1
```

Eventually I want to setup the default gateway like this :

```
sudo ip route add default scope global nexthop via 10.22.11.1 dev wlan0 weight nexthop via 10.22.11.1 dev wlan1 weight 1
```

but in-between I need to setup the main routing table and I don't know how to do this as in this case both nics are connected to the same network and share both network-address and gateway.

Can someone help me here?

Many thanks!

Comment: **This will not help you download large files**, or at least not over HTTP.  This type of setup is only useful to distribute multiple outgoing sessions between links.  It will not increase bandwidth for solitary transfer.  A connection to a single destination IP will only go through a single interface.  With the route robin setup, when a connection is made a temporary route is added for the cache for the source address to the destination and is limited to a single interface.

Comment: Why not? The idea is to use a download manager that splits a download into several connections that should be distributed amohg the adapters. My question is simply how to set up the routing table to achieve this. I know how to achieve this for the case that my adapters are connected to different APs, but not when they are connected to the same AP. That is what the question is about.